# Can I do anything with fonts for WIX installer on HDPI screen

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I'm using wix 3.10 to create installer for my product. When I start installer on HDPI screen(windows 10) all fonts looks blurred. Can I do something with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wix+dpi